# Mapping field name in model using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a way to map field names to a database to a different attribute name in the model? For example, if the database has a field name of `customer_id` but I wanted to use eloquent in this way `Customer::get(['id'])` I've tried using the getAttribute method but that is called after eloquent has attempted to get the value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use accessors to work with such attributes, but there's no way to query them this way with core eloquent.

But fear not! Use this package https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence and you can easily achieve what you want (`Mappable` in particular):

```
// Customer model
protected $maps =[
  'id' => 'customer_id',
  'name' => 'customer_name',
  ...
];

// then you can do this:
$customer = Customer::where('name', 'whatever')->first();
// calls WHERE customer_name = ? sql

$customer->id; // customer_id column
$customer->name; // customer_name column
$customer->name = 'different name'; // set mutator works as well
```

<strike>It's in heavy development and **currently `select` is not yet supported**, but it's matter of day or two.</strike> `select` support has been pushed already.

Comment: Can we use Mappable for relations as well?

Comment: In your model do not forget

use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence; //base trait
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mappable; // extension trait

and then inside your class

use Eloquence,Mappable;

This package is super! saves lot of time..

Comment: What about the return JSON if I want to use my new 'better' name in the response from POST, PU, GET, DELETE etc ?