# Laravel 5: DB column other name then Model name in Laravel

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel, schema

Can I make a schema which insert a Table with the name "User" and the columns "email", "password".

This I would like at this as a Model in Laravel for example `User.password`

But (know the question) I would like that Laravel write other table and columns names to the DB. For example Table "Table1" and columns "columns1" and "columns2".

Is this possible and if yes how can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Laravel actually uses the table `users` by default so if you wanted to create the table `User`, it should be no problem, albeit it would probably be confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping field name in model using laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979479/mapping-field-name-in-model-using-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $table = 'table_name';

protected $fillable=[
                 'columns1',
                 'columns2'
             ];
```